# Django, custom managers, base_manager_name and the failure to save model

Tags: django, django-models

I'll simplify my problem:

In my project I have a `Person` model and that person has an age. I changed the default manager applied to `Person` using `base_manager_name` to my version of `objects`.

Person` has this:

```
objects = MySpecialAgeFilterManager()
objects_all = models.Manager()
```

So, when I ask for `Person.objects.all()` I will get only people between the ages of 20 and 30. Don't ask me why-- it's just for the sake of this question..

I have a certain `Person` instance with the age of 10. That person will not show up on `Person.objects.all()` -- however it will be included in `Person.objects_all.all()`

My problem is this.

```
p = Person.objects_all.filter(age=10).first()    # works, I get my person. 
p.age = 20                                       # trying to bring him into the light....
p.save()                                         # CRASH!!!
```

The crash claims the `pk` for `p` creates a duplicate violation on the database. It's as if it's trying to save it with the `objects` scope in mind, and not the `objects_all` scope I retrieved that person with. In the `objects` context it doesn't exist so it tries to save... but the database has that PK already in use. The database doesn't care about Model Manager scopes....

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you add a *minimal reproducible example* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked:

Person.objects_all.filter(pk=p.id).update(age=20)

to sum it up, when you have a `base_manager_name` applied that's EXCLUSIVE. and you use it to get model rows in order to update it. Update via `.update` and not `save` because save doesn't work in the context of the special model manager you've obtained the object through.